# Como esconder postagens com uma certa marcação da pagina inicial do blogger

Tags: xml, blogger

Eu tenho alguns posts que são apenas javascript, e na pagina inicial aparece o javascript, Eu gostaria de esconder posts que contem a marcação "Esconder" da pagina inicial, **o que fazer?**.

**Eu tentei trocar isso:** `<b:include data='post' name='post'/>`
**Pos isso:**

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == "true"'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != "LabelYouWantToHide"'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post' />
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>
```

**Eu também tentei o conteúdo [desta pagina](http://template-data.blogspot.com/p/bwith.html).**

```
    <b:with var='posts'
            value='data:posts filter
                   (p => p.labels none
                         (l => l.name == "hide-me"))'>
    </b:with>
```

Mas isso esconde o post até na pagina do próprio post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encontre: `<b:include data='post' name='post'/>` e troque por:**

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels none ( l => l.name == "Esconder" )'>
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
  </b:if>
  <b:else/>
  <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
```